# Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/user/corda/build/nodes/Notary"): error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, corda, gradlew

I have cloned the Cordapp-template-kotlin repository and installed the token-sdk binaries, but when I run

```
./gradlew clean deployNodes
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.

  > Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/user/corda/build/nodes/Notary"): error=2, No such file or directory
  >   Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/user/corda/build/nodes/Notary"): error=2, No such file or directory

I have also checked the Java sdk, its set to the right place.

Comment: What does `java -version` report? Do you have `/home/user/corda/build/nodes/Notary` directory?

Comment: The error was with setting the java config.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be trying to run the command from a deleted folder. Either that, or you have not set up your java path correctly.

Comment: The folder exists and contains 1 folder called logs, 1 jar file called corda.jar and one node.conf file. Also My java path is also set correctly,
asad@AsadPc:~/Desktop/corda$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u211-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_211

I checked the path in the Project Structure also.